# Doctrine + Firebird via PDO

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, firebird

as everybody knows, Firebird is again added to official build of PHP, and has it's own PDO extension. I thought about connecting it with Doctrine2. Officialy, website of Doctrine2 project says that they don't support Firebird yet. But now it has own PDO extension, so maybe there is a way to use it?
Does anybody tried to connect Doctrine2 with PDO Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

There are some open issues for the Doctrine DBAL extension for Firebird: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-95